# Just one step away. Exponential formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

The data points are.

[image: The data points]

I have worked out that.

y =.032(2.5)^x  is correct where  my table is

x = 0, y = .032

x = 1, y = .08

x = 2, y = .2

How do I get my formula to reflect y=-3, x =.0320 ect..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Currently, you have it so that you get the value you want at $-3$ when $x=0$, and the value you want at $-2$ when $x=1$, and so on. Therefore, you want have an $x$ which is $3$ larger than it should be. How should you change your equation to reflect this?

Response to the comments: One of the subtleties in PEMDAS/BEDMAS is that certain things are secretly parentheses: $y=0.32(2.5)^{x-3}$ "really" means $y=0.32(2.5)^{(x-3)}$. Other things that do this include

- fractions: $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ is the same as $\frac{(a+b)}{(c+d)}$
- square roots: $\sqrt{x+y}$ is the same as $\sqrt{(x+y)}$
- Sometimes, composition of functions. No examples, because if you've seen it you've seen it and if not it'll just be confusing.

Comment: err. Need a little more help.

Comment: How do you write "the number three smaller than $x$" using algebraic notation?

Comment: I want to say the question your posing, underlines the problem that I understand is wrong. The implementation of what making -3 less is what is throwing me off. I cannot be as simple as subtracting 3. It must be division? Divide by 1/3 I am not sure.

Comment: Nope: It is indeed as simple as subtracting by $3$. The only subtlety is that you don't want to subtract $y$ by 3, you want to subtract $x$ by 3. But this is fine, you can just do that: $$y=0.32(2.5)^{x-3}$$ If you wanted to subtract $y$ by 3 instead, it would be $$y=0.32(2.5)^x-3$$

Comment: ok. It makes sense. What is still not clear (to me) is the order of operation on the exponent. y=0.32(2.5)x−3 When working out the function the fist step after plugging in x is to subtract from the exponent?

Comment: Ah, that is a good point: see the edited answer.

Comment: My ti-89 does not like y=0.32(2.5)^(x−3) - it imeditily simplifies the problem to .002048(2.5)^x then when x = -3 y = .00013 I am plugging it into y= just like 'y=0.32(2.5)^(x−3)' any ideas?

Comment: Exercise: Show that the two expressions are equivalent. (If you understand well how exponents work, this should be easy. If it's not easy, then it's a good opportunity to get more intuition for how exponents work.)

Comment: My math is wrong. The solution is .5(2.5)^x

Comment: I have to sleep will be back tomorrow to check in on what I did wrong.

Comment: Nope, you're not wrong, I'm wrong. We want $x+3$, since if $x=-3$ you want it to be $0.032(2.5)^0$ which means that you want $0=-3+3$, not $-3-3$. Fixing answer now. However, it is true that $0.032(2.5)^{x+3}=.5(2.5)^x$, so the (spirit of the) exercise still stands.